# Hours aren't working on Stopwatch

Tags: javascript, settimeout, increment, stopwatch

I'm making a stopwatch with seconds, minutes, and hours.  I want the stopwatch to reset and restart after the hours reach 59.  Also, when minutes reach 59 I want the hour hands to increment.  It doesn't seem to work.  The left hour "hand", if you will, won't increment.. even when I stated that I wanted it to.

***PLEASE NOTE SPEED "5" ON SETTIMEOUT.  I SPED IT UP TO TEST HOURS.  SHOULD BE "1000".***

**HTML:**

```
    <ul>

        <li id="hour-greater">0</li>
        <li id="hour-lesser">0</li>
        <li>:</li>
        <li id="min-greater">0</li>
        <li id="min-lesser">0</li>
        <li>:</li>
        <li id="sec-greater">0</li>
        <li id="sec-lesser">0</li>

    </ul>
```

**JS:**

```
(function() {

    var secLesser = document.getElementById("sec-lesser").value,
    secGreater = document.getElementById("sec-greater").value,
    minLesser = document.getElementById("min-lesser").value,
    minGreater = document.getElementById("min-greater").value,
    hourLesser = document.getElementById("hour-lesser").value,
    hourGreater = document.getElementById("hour-greater").value;


    function stopWatch(){
        secLesser++;
        if(secLesser > 9) {
            secLesser = 0;
            secGreater++;
        } else if(secGreater + secLesser == 14){
            secGreater = 0;
            secLesser = 0;
            minLesser++;
        } else if(minLesser > 9){
            minLesser = 0;
            minGreater++;
        } else if(minGreater + minLesser == 14){
            secGreater = 0;
            secLesser = 0;
            hourLesser++;
        } else if(hourLesser > 9){
            hourLesser = 0;
            hourGreater++;
        } else if(hourGreater + hourLesser == 14){
            alert("It's been 59 hours... leave this page!");
        } 

        document.getElementById("sec-lesser").textContent = secLesser;
        document.getElementById("sec-greater").textContent = secGreater;
        document.getElementById("min-lesser").textContent = minLesser;
        document.getElementById("min-greater").textContent = minGreater;
        document.getElementById("hour-lesser").textContent = hourLesser;
        document.getElementById("hour-greater").textContent = hourGreater;
        window.setTimeout(stopWatch, 5);
    }

    stopWatch();
})();
```

Comment: Um, that is not a great way to code a stop watch since setTimeout is not accurate and does other weird things when the page/tab is minimized/hidden.

Comment: I understand that.  I also noticed it while making it.  I'll use setInterval.. just want to know why the hours aren't working.. ;)

Comment: setInterval is no better!

Comment: lol well I'll research the best way!  Also I'll be using spans, not an li.. I didn't want to spend a lot of time on how I coded it

Comment: do you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/chepe263/A3a9m/

Comment: Something like this would be more accurate and probably what you want to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/wA2rF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the part where you have

```
} else if(minGreater + minLesser == 14){
            secGreater = 0;
            secLesser = 0;
            hourLesser++;
```

should be resetting minGreater and minLesser not secGreater/secLesser. Change it to:

```
} else if(minGreater + minLesser == 14){
            minGreater = 0;
            minLesser = 0;
            hourLesser++;
```

Oh and look into [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) as better alternative to setTimeout/setInterval.